# Want to parse post data to client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, ejs

I have array of object on express

```
const postNuke = []
```

I am pushing data using post request

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const title = req.body.title_text
    const description = req.body.description
    const detail = req.body.textarea

    postNuke.push({
        title,
        description,
        detail
    })
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

and parsing data to html using ejs

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {list: postNuke})
})
   <ul>
      <%for(let i=0; i<listItems.length; i++ ) {%>
        <li><%= listItems[i] %></li>
      <%}%>
 </ul>
```

but getting error on my home page

```
[object,object]
```

how can I parse my object into html using ejs is there any way of doing it?

Comment: where is the `listItems` in your render payload? Shouldn't you loop through `list` instead?

Comment: Thanks! but I figured myself out it was easy but you know you gotta keep trying here is the answer if someone requires it in case of :<ul>
      <% for(let i = 0; i<listItems.length; i++) { %>
        <li><%= JSON.stringify(listItems[i]) %></li>
     <% }%>
  </ul>